# Framework import issue in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Here the problem: For a project at work we need to include an extern API: mobileAppTrackeriOS from HasOffers.

It gives us a framework to include in our projet and instruction to enter in our code.
So I copy the framework in the project directory and drag it into xcode to include it.
But when i want to use it with:

```
#import <framework/mainheader.h>
```

The build give me an error :

```
Lexical or Processor issue 'MobileAppTrackeriOS_arc/MobileAppTracker.h' file not found
```

I check the framework search path in my target build setting, my main directory where is the framework is here.

I test with "" instead of <> same issue...

i cleaned and rebuilt, try to include directly the header... many ridiculous things... no changes.

So what I forget?

I'm on Xcode 4.5 and develop for iOS 6.0.

Comment: Finaly i extracted the headers from the framework and directly import them...
It's working but i'm not satisfied by this solution...

Answer (score 0):

A question, can you see if the framework is in Build Phases -> Link binary with Libraries?

If answer is not, you must add in this section.